# How to return data from sql server 2008 using android date format?

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I am trying to fetch information from SQL Server 2008 R2 using Android date picker.

Here is my plan:

1. Setup a date range like from date,to date
2. Create a button and then fetch information from sql server using a query

But the key point is my to and from range will send request to server like `2016-10-03 to 2016-10-10`(that mean 3th October,2016 to 10th October,2016). Now here is the key point the SQL Server date data store using Getdate() method that's mean it's YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format how to convert this into android provide data while sending any request. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use simpledate format and parse YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM to whatever format you like.

Check this : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Wow... I applaud the 80's throwback handle @zerocool Such a great flick.

Answer (score 1):

From the SQL point of view, if you are sending a `DATE` and your DB has `DATETIME` then it really depends on your query. The best way is `<`

```
SELECT someColumn 
FROM someTable 
WHERE dateColumn >= @startDate AND dateColumn < DATEADD(dd,1,@endDate)
```

The point I'm making is to include the date of your end date, add one day and filter where it's less than that. This is equivalent to adding `23:59:59.999` to your end date and using the <= operand. It's just less work and a wee bit more accurate depending on your use case. You can set your endDate to +1 in your application or the query. This is assuming that although your DB uses `DATETIME`, the time is in fact populated with something other than `00:00:00.000`. Of the time portion is `00:00:00.000` then you can just pass in your date since by default, it has a time of `00:00:00.000`